# Key shortcut (hotkey) in Visual Studio to open a file inside your solution?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a key shortcut in Visual Studio to find & open a file inside your solution without using Resharper or any other tools?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer is **outdated**; [see here for latest information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164379/55246).

---

Not a single keystroke, but yes: `Ctrl+D > o f  filename` (so that's five keystrokes before you start typing the filename).  It then autocompletes the filename for you.

You need the Find box in the toolbar for this to work.

(If you change your mind about addins, [SonicFileFinder](http://www.jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/index.htm) is for this very purpose, and free.)

Comment: This is what i'm looking for. However, when I try to open a file VS, its telling me that "The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the file specified." This doesn't make sense since VS was giving me this file  in intellisence.

Also I found this: http://geekswithblogs.net/hongyes/archive/2009/03/23/visual-studio-tip-navigate-to-file-by-typing-file-name.aspx  

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that error, I'm afraid.  It's always worked perfectly for me.  Sorry...

Comment: Visual Assist X has a pretty nifty Alt+Shift+O that does essentially the same thing, and it shows you a dialog of all files that match the current substring you've typed in so far while you type.

Comment: This answer is deprecated. Check this for newer versions of Visual Studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003445/key-shortcut-in-visual-studio-to-open-a-file-inside-your-solution/44164379#44164379

Answer (score 136):

The accepted solution **doesn't** work on the newer versions.
For **Visual Studio 2022**, and **2019**, **2017**  do the following:

**Update 1:**
Now, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and typing the file name works!

**Update 2:**
Since Visual Studio 2019 now it's possible to do a similar search via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.
But it works slightly **sloppy** since it shows VS-related stuff as well.

**Original answer:**

1. Press these keys to open the "Go to" popup:
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
   <kbd>,</kbd>
2. Type there:
   <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> *Filename*
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

*Notes*:

- We are writing `f`  to make VS search only on files. We can
  also, use other letters. For more info type `?` in the "Go to" popup.
- For **more keys** and for **Visual Studio 2012** to **2015** take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776697/how-to-quickly-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-2012/41038705#41038705)
  answer.

Comment: Microsoft employees should spend a while working with a Jetbrains IDE such as IntelliJ IDEA to find out how IDEs should really work!

Comment: I've been using 2017 forever now and had no idea this functionality was in there.  Awesome!!!  The only question I have is is it possible to make that a floating/dockable window.  I personally hate that 'shove it up in the corner' thing they have going on. It's *REALLY* annoying on large screens with multiple panes because it show up in so many different places!

Comment: Sadly there is no such floating functionality at this moment, but it's possible to make the bar appear in the center instead of corner.  
To do so, open the settings of that panel (Ctrl+, then Alt+Shift+G) and check "Center Window"

Comment: Ctrl + shift + t then type filename and enter or select

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe, good news. Now in the preview version of the Visual Studio 2022 (v17.3 Preview 1.1) that window is floating. You can either download the preview version or wait a bit till they release

Comment: @WillCalderwood I have used Visual Studio for years before switching to a JetBrains IDE.  I still think Visual Studio is the best IDE I've used, but IntelliJ is a very close second.  Although I will admit I stumbled on this question trying to find the equivalent of "double shift -> find all" when having to go back to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, which puts the `>` in place for you automatically.

Comment: If you do not have the "Go To Find Combo Box" on your toolbar, this will not work. To add it, click on drop down at the end of the Standard Toolbar > Add > Find (listed after Find in Files).

Comment: Official documentation for the Find/Command Box https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1665hyw1.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Similar to [Just Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164379/5734097)'s answer I discover that, on **[Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/14/new-code-navigation-shortcuts-in-visual-studio-2017/)**, you can do the following:

> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, then <kbd>f</kbd>

Or you could go to `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard`
and change the shortcut of `Edit.GoToFile` for whatever you like.

---

I replaced mine with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Well, "[Ctrl] + [,] then [f]" is not only similar to @JustShadow's answer, but also is the same solution provided by him :)

Comment: Sorry, that was a ``copy`` ``paste``problem. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: damned, I have been searching for this "Edit.GoToFile" forever, I always searched for "GoTo" and I never got the result. big thanks

Answer (score 0):

Options => Projects and Solutions => **Track Active Item in Solution Explorer**