# How to quickly open a file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying VS2012 RC but find one good feature no available any more (or if it still is, please let me know): in VS2010, if I know a file name, for example, `MyFile.cs`, I can quickly open it by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or whatever shortcut assigned) to go to Find tool, and then type `>of myfile.cs`, the file will be opened then, and it is even more convenient that this will do an incremental search of the file name. In the whole procedure I don't need to use mouse at all.

The new Quick Launch tool in VS2012 only searches in opened files, which is really not what I want. Does this feature get supported in VS2012? Is so or if some similar way exists, please tell me.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> then *filename* then <kbd>enter</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks -- this is great! I don't have ReSharper installed on 2012 yet but in the meantime I just remapped Window.SolutionExplorerSearch from Ctrl + ; to Ctrl + Shift + T and it has been working nicely!

Comment: This would be perfect if it would clear the selection after opening the file. As it is, having to manually clear it with the mouse makes it nearly useless. :-( I want a sublime text style onebox open file/search symbol/goto line addin for VS.

Comment: @ChrisHynes To clear out selection... you can hit Ctrl + ; again and then hit ESC key, which will clear out the field.  If you hit ESC another time, it will put your focus back in the code editor as well.  (Not ideal, but better than nothing.)

Comment: This is way too slow, it doesn't update the list until you stop typing and wait a couple seconds.  It's unusable.  I need something like Xcode/Eclipse's functionality, which updates in realtime.

Comment: I found its too slow when the project size is two large. In smaller project is returning quickly.

Answer (score 151):

Look into the EDIT Menu at Navigate To... Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: This shortcut (and others) can also be modified in the Tools...Options...Environment...Keyboard menu if you want to match it to other IDEs.

Comment: [NavigateToAll](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbc361a-ee69-4ba3-83ff-ab2e8122ff47) makes Navigate To even better by allowing you to open _any_ file, not just the ones in the solution. I found this especially useful for large projects.

Comment: Can we edit all shortkey to same resharper shortkey?

Answer (score 82):

I wish there is a simple shortcut to just open a file within a solution.

These 3 are close but none of them is perfect.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> has a delay and does not clear your search after you open the file.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> takes too long initially and it shows method names etc, showing a lot of irrelevant results if you just want to open a file.
3. Using Command Window you have to type `open` or `of`, but in some cases this could/might be the fastest.
   Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open the Command Window, then type `of your_filename`
   [image: screenshot of action]

Comment: Really useful Ctrl+, and Ctrl+Alt+A shortcuts.

Comment: In `Ctrl+,`, you can type `?` for help which tells you that prefixing your query with e.g. `f` will allow you to search only files.

Comment: Dan's solution is great, but requires VS 2017.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + A is the best thing that i learned today. Thanks it seems to be the fastest at least for me.

Answer (score 22):

You can put this back onto the Standard toolbar as follows.

- Right click the toolbar and select Customize
- Go to the Commands Tab
- Select the Toolbar radio button
- Then select Standard from the combo box
- Select the Add Command button
- Select Edit from the Categories list
- Then find and select "Go To Find Combo" from the Commands list and press OK
- Move it to where you want it to appear in the toolbar and press Close to save it.

Done!

//*Ergin

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for, since it emulates the behavior in previous versions of Visual Studio.  However, this answer was a little confusing for me to read, so I submitted an edited version for peer review, to make it a little more readable for others.

Comment: At least in vs2015 this "find combo" in my toolbar did NOT allow me to open files by name. It behaved exquivalent to a find-in-document except pressing enter doesnt even find next, I had to use F3.

Comment: ctrl + shift + t does the same

Answer (score 14):

Actually, there are many methods for switching to files without touching the mouse.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and type a file name: Switches to the selected file  (I think this is what you need)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>: Switches to the previously opened file
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>: Does the same in reverse order

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Again switches to previous file
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Does the same in reverse order

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times: Switches to selected file
Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and release <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then select file with <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys:  Switches to selected file

**Update:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003445/key-shortcut-in-visual-studio-to-open-a-file-inside-your-solution/44164379#44164379) is the solution for newer versions of **Visual Studio** (2017, 2019)

Answer (score 7):

Since I don't care for any of these approaches for just locating files, I use the [VSFileNav extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af) in VS 2012. If you know the filename, or part of it, it is much quicker than most of the other approaches, especially for large solutions. I mostly only use the Solution Explorer search for instances where I remember an object name but not the filename.

Comment: Despite the lack of upvotes, I've found this (the VSFileNav extension) to be the best solution currently on this page, having tried them all. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "code" command to open saved/new files quickly in VS.

For Mac Users
Press `command+shift+p`, a search bar will open at the top in VS

Search for code, "Install code command in PATH" will prompt
Press enter.

**Now can open any file or new file with code filename or code -r filename