# command-t or fuzzy finder for visual studio that's not resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, fuzzyfinder

Is there an alternative to ReSharper's navigation capabilities? That works fine, but Resharper itself slows down my computer too much, even with most stuff turned off. So, I'm looking for some plugin that only does navigation, like vim's command-t plugin.

Comment: A good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Visual_Studio_extensions

Comment: (voting to close because 'shopping' questions are considered a poor fit for the Stack Exchange model)

Comment: ReSharper shouldn't be that slow. Try to disable all Visual Studio extensions other than ReSharper. Upgrade to 7.0 or at least to 6.1.1. Disable solution wide code analysis (Code Inspections -> Settings -> Analyze errors in whole solution).

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy I've done all of that.

Comment: @me-, including upgrade to 7.0?

Comment: @me-, you can make a performance snapshot (ReSharper | Help | Profile Visual Studio) and open a bugreport at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com . We'll try to do something about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has support for something similar with its Quick Launch feature. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776697/how-to-quickly-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-2012) for additional information.

Comment: Thank you Fammy. I plan on upgrading in two weeks so that works perfect for me.

Comment: It's not as good as command-t as it only open files you currently have open. It does not select from the entire solution and it is not a fuzzy finder. You have to put in exact substrings of the match

Comment: You get what you pay for, I guess. ;)