# how to open file by name in VS2012 express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

In Visual Web Developer Express 2010  pressing Ctrl+O and entering

`>of index`

shows file list and allows to select and open proper file. How to do same thing in Visual Studio Express 2012 ?

I tried Ctrl+Q and typed

> of index

Tried also

index

in both cases "no search result available" message appears.

Comment: are you looking for the "Navigate to" option: `Ctrl+,`

Comment: I pressed Ctrl+, and Ctrl+. in main and numeric keyboards but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have a "Navigate to" in the Edit menu?

Comment: No. Edit menu contains Undo, Redo,Cut,Copy,Paste,Delete,Select all,Find and replace, Go To, Format Document, Format selection,Advanced,Bookmarks,Outlining, Intellisense and Refactor.

Comment: Can you check under `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` if you write "NavigateTo" in `Show commands containing` does it show up there?

Comment: Thank you. After typing Navigate to there nothing is shown. I found solution to restore it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776697/how-to-quickly-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-2012 last answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quickly open a file in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776697/how-to-quickly-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-2012)