# Is there VS2012 "go to file" plugin?

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2012, resharper

My resharper license just finished
and until we'll buy a new one I was wondering if there is a plugin for VS2012 that is like the 
"go to file" (I think it ctrl+shift+T) ?

It is my single most used operation in resharper (basically since we are working in c++)

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594037/is-there-a-tool-to-quickly-locate-a-file-in-visual-studio-similar-to-eclipses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776697/how-to-quickly-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: thx alliswell. Sonic FileFinder did the job

Answer (score 2):

In VS2012 there's a function to "Sync with active document" where the currently open file will be selected in the **Solution Explorer**. If this is what you mean by "go to file" then you can simply type `Ctrl+[` and `s` to do it.

You can also click on the double arrow button in the **Solution Explorer** to select the currently open window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Edit -> Navigate To`
and see shortcut defined for your Visual Studio.

> [image: navigate to]

Default would be:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (Ctrl+Comma) enter filename and goto file.

Comment: This shortcut is overwritten when Resharper is installed; that's why it doesnt work. So you have to remap it; or you can just disable resharper and reset your keyboard - until you will get new resharper license.